# Arma 2, Arma 2 OA, and Combined Ops

Tags: steam, windows, ubuntu, arma-2

So I have both Arma 2 and Arma 2 OA, and, on my old PC, I had them both installed and had run arma 2 once. I then launched from Arma 2 OA and had access to everything available in both games.

Now, my old PC was destroyed, and on my new PC, I have something of a unique space situation where my Windows partition only has around 15 GB available (not including space taken by the OS). So what I do is move games I've downloaded to my Ubuntu partition using Steam mover, which creates a shortcut in the common folder, then move them back when I want to play.

My question is, do I need to download both Arma 2 and Arma 2 OA having run  arma 2 once before on another PC, and if so, can Arma 2 be on another partition  and still give me access to the correct things in OA? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to download both Arma 2 and Arma 2 OA having run arma 2 once before on another PC?

You do need the games to run atleast once, not sure in what machine matters or not but it shouldn't.

> Can Arma 2 be on another partition and still give me access to the correct things in OA

It should be no problem at all aslong as you link them properly with SteamMover.